# what does TS Emit Failed mean in Typescript?

Tags: angularjs, typescript, atom-editor

I keep getting the little red popup saying "TS Emit Failed" when I press cmd+S. Console doesn't show any error. What can be wrong or what can lead to this alert? Can someone explain it to me? Thanks.

[screenshot of the error on Atom](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RvElz.png)

And here is my tsconfig.json file

```
{ 
"compileOnSave": true,
"compilerOptions": {
    "module": "commonjs",
    "target": "es6",
    "sourceMap": true,
    "experimentalDecorators": true,
    "emitDecoratorMetadata": true,
    "noEmitHelpers": true,
    "noEmitOnError": true
},
"exclude": [
    "node_modules",
    "platforms"
] 
}
```

Answer (score 3):

Typescript is a "superset" of JavaScript, which means that it includes all of JavaScript and then a lot of extra things like the ability to set types and nicer syntax. While web browsers or node know how to interpret and run JavaScript, they won't be able to understand all of the extra things that Typescript allows. This means that before it can be used, Typescript has to be "transpiled" (like compiling, but it doesn't convert source code into machine code, but rather transforms Typescript source code into JavaScript source code, that in turn can be interpreted by the browser).

When the transpiler runs, it "emits" JavaScript. What this error probably means is that you have an error in your Typescript that prevents it from being successfully traspiled into JavaScript, i.e. the transpiler cannot emit proper JavaScript.

If you want help figuring out what's causing the error, you should post your code. :)

### Update

This issue is [discussed in this thread](https://github.com/TypeStrong/atom-typescript/issues/467). Essentially, the `JS Outdated` error means that the `.js` file that was compiled when you last saved does not match the `.js` file that would be emitted if you compiled the current code in your `.ts` file. It seems that some people have had this show up even when they have saved. Try updating `atom-typescript` and/or specifying the `out` property in your `tsconfig.json`.

Comment: hi @morphatic ,thanks for your reply.  I've updated my question.